# Swapping BODY content while keeping state

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom, state

Dynamically swapping BODY content using jQuery html function works as expected with 'static' content.

But if forms are being used, current state of inputs is lost.

The jQuery detach function, which should keep page state, seems to be blanking out the whole page.

The following code is the initial idea using jQuery html but of course the text input value will always empty.

```
  function swap1( ) {

    $("body").html('<button onclick="swap2();">SWAP2</button><input type="text" placeholder="swap2"/>');

  }

  function swap2( ) {

    $("body").html('<button onclick="swap1();">SWAP1</button><input type="text" placeholder="swap1"/>');


  }
```

With not knowing what form inputs there are, how would one swap in and out these forms in the BODY and keep track of the form states?

Demo of two text inputs which should keep state when they come back into the BODY:

https://jsfiddle.net/g7hksfne/3/

Comment: maybe your approach is the problem; why cleaning all the HTML inside body when you could simply hide it? Then your state won't be lost.

Comment: @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz yes, for a simple case then you could do it that way. fortunately ( :) ) it's a complex case.

Comment: @zaf Can you explain why you can't simply hide the existing page and show a secondary one?  I'm struggling to think of a reason your proposed solution makes more sense, and I'm being very generous!

Comment: I updated your fiddle to do it in a similar way to your approach, but instead of using strings for the HTML content, I use the jQuery `clone` method: https://jsfiddle.net/g7hksfne/4/ - maybe this helps...

Comment: @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz thats the expected behaviour! let me test it out fully and i'll get back. thank you!

Comment: @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz That won't work, as after cloning, you're still replacing the HTML contents, thus discarding the state again. You have to edit the DOM directly where it is needed instead of replacing the complete tree.

Comment: @Archer hiding and showing would probably require more layout infrastructure, ids/names would probably have to be more unique, javascript/selectors would have to be more selective, etc. if it was static content then visual hide/show would be fine. The case here is that there are multiple interactive apps which must be sandboxed with minimal surgery.

Comment: @Felix it works, I tried it. I agree that replacing the whole tree is overkill, but can't think of a better way to do it without simply hiding.

Comment: @zaf I think that you are confusing the mechanism here. Hiding and showing requires less acrobatics and it's for sure quicker. I will add a snippet later if it can be helpful.

Comment: In its most simple case, hiding could be done with `document.querySelector("insert some selector here").style.display = should_be_hidden ? "none" : "";`

Comment: I have to agree with @ÓscarGómezAlcañiz.  You can duplicate the existing page and then hide the original, with 1 line of code.  This really sounds like a case of trying to work a solution, rather than fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: missunderstood use case. This covers saving the state *while* manipulating the DOM, instead of switching between different states.

Instead of replacing the `<body>`'s content by serializing and parsing HTML, learn how to use the DOM. Only replace the parts of the DOM you actually change, so the rest of it can keep its state (which is stored in the DOM).

In your case: you might want to use something like this:

```js
function swap1( ) {
    document.querySelector("button").onclick = swap2;
    document.querySelector("button").textContent = "SWAP2";
    document.querySelector("input").placeholder = "swap2";
}

function swap2( ) {
    document.querySelector("button").onclick = swap1;
    document.querySelector("button").textContent = "SWAP1";
    document.querySelector("input").placeholder = "swap1";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="swap1();">SWAP1</button><input type="text" placeholder="swap1"/>
```

(This is not optimized and should only serve as an example.)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem: the state of inputs is not preserved. If you type anything inside the inputs, after swapping back and forth the value is lost.

Comment: I have created a runnable snippet. It does preserve state, so you might have done something differently.

Comment: I see what you mean! I think @zaf is asking something different: I understood he needs the state of the *different* inputs to be preserved, so the state _comes back_ when swapping for the second time. Can you confirm @zaf?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, my answer covers a different use case. Will post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the content you want to save in a node below `<body>`, like a simple ´` if you don't already have a container. When you want to save and replace the container, use something like:

```
var saved_container = document.body.removeChild(document.querySelector("#app_container");
// or document.getElementById/getElementsByClassName, depends on container
```

The element is now detached and you can add your secondary to `document.body`. When you want to get back, save the secondary content (without overwriting the first container of course), then reattach the primary content it with:

```
document.body.appendChild(savedContainer);
```